# Nginx URL masking to another domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I just installed Nginx as a feature of VestaCP on my VPS.

What I'm trying to do is to mask the URL `http://example.com` to `http://12345.com`, so when users visit `http://example.com/path/file.mp4` they will see the content of `http://12345.com/path/file.mp4` but browsers still show the URL `http://example.com/path/file.mp4`.

I googled and found a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645018/nginx-url-masking-to-a-different-domain). It looks like the answer I'm looking for. However when I applied his code to nginx.conf, VestaCP showed `Error: nginx failed to start with new config` and stopped working.

Here is the code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass https://123.12.12.12;
    rewrite ^/$ /path last;
    }
}
```

Is this the right solution for me? I'm completely new to this so I don't know if I did it correctly.

Edited: I was able to get the job done using apache .htaccess. How do I convert this to use with Nginx?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://12345.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need below, no rewrite needed

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
       proxy_pass https://123.12.12.12;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error when trying to save the config file `Error: nginx failed to start with new config`

Comment: Run `nginx -t`, there might be some other config also getting loaded. Use `find /etc/nginx -name "*conf*"` to see what all configs are there

Comment: This is what it shows when I run the command: 
`
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
`