# Connect Shopify store specific page or path to your subdomain

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, shopify, hosting

How to connect a specific page of your Shopify store page to your domain?

**Important, not the shop itself, just a specific path/page.**
For example:

https://the-landing-test.myshopify.com/**blogs/news** -> https://journal.landing.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is to use [Stealth Forwarding](https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/whats-stealth-forward).

Although it has few [drawbacks](https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/stealth-drawbacks) it was the only way of accomplishing what I needed.

**1 way of doing it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645018/nginx-url-masking-to-a-different-domain?fbclid=IwAR0ql-6VdTkr3k-siQnO1qA3WLls2NSoIkRrYN5Uurw-E6QYFv5pXnJQcVE), with Nginx.**